# Android Gradle 5+ Maven Publish Local

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, maven-publish

I have a useful library built for my own Android development to be easier. I consider making it a third party library into maven local repository so that I can use it with other projects.

After read a lot of online tutorial, I got this:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId libraryGroupId
            artifactId libraryBaseName
            version libraryVersion

            artifact bundleReleaseAar
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Gradle 5.1.1 with Android Gradle Plugin version 3.4.1.

Error when sync project:

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not get unknown property 'bundleReleaseAar' for object of type org.gradle.api.publish.maven.internal.publication.DefaultMavenPublication.
```

Do I need to create custom artifact `bundleReleaseAar`? And how?
Please help me fix this.

Comment: @M.Ricciuti, you are right. Thank you.